# Pass picture to CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.pictureobject in runtime

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to give a PictureObject (in my crystal report) ,path or something
i use this line in C#.net :

**PictureObject oPicture =(PictureObject) rptClass.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["pPicture"];**

but i don't have that option.

can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem:  [Importing Dynamic Images to the Crystal Report](http://aspalliance.com/1097_Importing_Dynamic_Images_to_the_Crystal_Report_without_Database_Overhead_using_Visual_Studio_2005.all)